# Es culpa de un problema de ciclado?

Tags: python

tengo un script con unas funciones con las que puedo añadir palabras a una lista y usando `if` en conjunto con otra funcion puedo ver si en un string existe esa palabra y invocar funciones, el problema es cuando hago debug y pongo 'hola' que esta en la lista y todo bien pero si  pongo 'adios' no funciona, puede ser por un problema de ciclado?

```
shards = []

def add_shard(shard:str):
    shards.append(str(shard))

def parameters(context:str):
    context == context.split(' ')
    for ccx in shards:
        if ccx in context:
            return ccx
        else: return False

def add_shard(shard:str):
        shards.append(str(shard))

inp = input('> ')

add_shard("hola")
add_shard("adios")
if parameters(inp) == 'hola':
    print("hola")
else:
    if parameters(inp) == 'adios':
        print("adios")
```

Comment: No cambies el código, que invalida las respuestas.

Comment: Revertimos la edición @CandidMoe?

Comment: @DanteS. No me había dado cuenta, pues con Pycharm la diferencia entre "==" y "=" es insignificante. Sólo lo vi cuando revise la pregunta publicada.

Comment: ANONIMO: por favor revierte la edición, pues si corriges el código entonces el problema desaparece y la pregunta pierde todo sentido (tendrá que ser cerrada).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta es la función correcta:

```
def parameters(context:str):
    context = context.split(' ')
    for ccx in shards:
        if ccx in context:
            return ccx
    return False
```

el problema con el original es que hace un `return False` si la palabra buscada (`context`) no es la primera en `shards`.

Hay que cambiar la lógica: iterar `shards` hasta encontrar alguna de las palabras recibidas y retornarla.

Si se termina la iteración sin retornar, quiere decir que no está, y se devuelve `False`.

Además ocupas un doble igual ("==", comparación) en lugar de un simple igual ("=", asignación). Entonces, la línea

```
context == context.split(' ')
```

es una expresión lógica que se evalua `True/False`, pero que no cambia `context` en ningun caso.

La forma correcta es:

```
context = context.split(' ')
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarle eso ultimo!!! Además, gracias por defenderme antes nwn

Comment: si coloco 'hola' y 'adios' en la misma linea no funciona al usar el metodo split

Comment: @ANONIMO problemas diferentes, preguntas diferentes. Permite que otros usen tus soluciones y no edites la pregunta, se vuelve un hilo inútil para los que lo vean en el futuro